# Date unable to be displayed

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to fetch and display all user information from mysql database but it doesn't able to show the time on row, but the rest information such as User ID and Username can be displayed. If I run the system in my windows localhost it's just working fine but when I run it using web hosting it doesn't show the date.

**Database :**
[image]

**Database Record :**
[image]

**My current coding :**

```
<?php
    $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM tbluserinfo";
    $result = $conn->query($sql_select);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['user_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['user_name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['user_created_date']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<td colspan='3' style='color: red;'>No record found.</td>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: will you please add ss of your db records

Comment: Inside the while loop, add ```echo "<p><pre>".print_r($row,true)."</pre></p>";``` That should show what your query is returning (including column names)

Comment: @SloanThrasher I added those line in my coding and the result is the **user_created_date** value as shown in the database record in the ss above

Comment: have u imported your connection

Comment: @AmrAly Yes I did. I managed to display the userid and username but it unable to display **only** `date`

Comment: Have you tried "View Source" in the browser to see if the value is there but not displayed for some reason? Also, have you tried to copy and paste the column name from the echo output into the php code? Just in case there's a hard to see typo or special character.

Comment: `echo date('j F, Y', strtotime($row['user_created_date']))`

Comment: @AmrAly I tried those but it showing wrong date such as `1 January, 1970`

Comment: @AmrAly it's not a string format, its a timestamp.

Comment: @EatenTaik it gives you this date if your `user_created_date` is empty please try ro add user again and check the result

Comment: @AmrAly my record all inserted successfully. If you see my question above I post it together with the ss of my database record and `user_created_date` has value

Comment: i meant your displayed date after your loop still the same?

Comment: @AmrAly yes it's just the same

Comment: @AmrAly I found out that my varable `user_created_date` has space in front of it. It's now working with your code. Thanks!

Comment: I will post my code as answer and i hope you accept it

Comment: @AmrAly ya sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try :

```
echo date('j F, Y', strtotime($row['user_created_date']));
```

and make sure your `$row['user_created_date']` is not null otherwise it will give you this date:

`1 January, 1970`